# Google app engine development server does not update web.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, jetty

The development server updates .jsp and servlets files, but it does not update web.xml. So, the mapping doesn't work/update.

If I deploy to google app engine, everything works great (online).

What can I do to fix the development server ?

Platform: GAE, Java, Eclipse

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never stopped the server after using it. After I stopped them, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, even stopping the server and starting it again didn't work. So, for testing purpose I changed the port number and deployed the application on the new port.